# Android apk obfuscation

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I am trying to obfuscate my android application. But not able to achieve the result.

In the tool it prompts "The input doesn't contain any classes. Did you specify the proper '-injars' options?"

So, does it mean my input file is already obfuscated? How do I differentiate between a normal APK and an obfuscated APK?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using proguard as a standalone tool, or using it in Eclipse as part of the sign apk process?

Comment: using standalone proguard tool

Comment: Please add your proguard config file to your question

Comment: use APKTools and try to decompile your app. That's the best way i know to verify a correct obfuscation :)